# Server Performance experience share

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, ubuntu

I would like to know your expertise for high traffic site to choose a sever with backend.

I am familiar with PHP, NodeJS and Go programming languages. Also these days more popular HTTP servers are Apache and NGINX. I am happy to know your experience with following combinations in performance and features like load balance, low overhead, security. for high traffic site.

- NGINX + PHP
- NGINX + NodeJS
- NGINX + Go
- Apache + PHP
- Apache + NodeJS
- Apache + Go
- NodeJS HTTP Server
- Go HTTP Server

I am planning to move my website to AWS so I would like to which is best for that.

I am looking for general information from you.

OS: Linux / Ubuntu

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)